# Testing that one model "belongs_to" another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, belongs-to

I have two models - Tenant and User, each tenant will have_many users and I am trying to find a way of testing that the ability to create a user and automatically assign tenant. When I try run the test I am getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method 'reflect_on_association' for Proc:Class
```

Tenant Code:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :billing_email, :country

validates :name,       :presence => true,
                       :length => { :maximum => 75 },
                       :uniqueness => true

validates :billing_email, :email => true

has_many :users
end
```

User Code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :tenant_id

validates :email,       :presence => true,
                        :uniqueness => true,
                        :email => true

validates :first_name,  :presence => true,
                        :length => { :maximum => 50 }

validates :last_name,   :presence => true,
                        :length => { :maximum => 50 }

validate :password_validation

has_many :sessions, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :tenant  

end
```

Test Attempt:

```
lambda do
  @attr = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
  post users_path, :user => @attr
  response.should be_success
end.should belong_to(:tenant)
```

Comment: Your test makes no sense - a lambda object doesn't belong to anything much. That aside, as a non-rspec user I cannot see the point of things like belong_to(:tenant). What's wrong with finding the new user and asserting that its tenant is X?

Comment: Hi noodl, I guess that is basically what I am looking to do but I guess that I am going about it in the wrong way. Is there any easier way of doing this as I was unaware that the lambda was the wrong approach, I am new to Rails and am basing my test efforts from tutorial examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not particularly clear what you're trying to achieve here. Asserting that one object "belongs_to" another smells bad. Do you really care that belongs_to was used for the association? Too often it seems that rspec tests end up duplicating the code under test without actually testing anything useful.

More likely you're interested to see if the result of POSTing to your controller produces the correct results. Since you haven't shown us your controller and since I think RSpec is pointless noise, here's how I'd tackle this..

```rb
assert_difference ->{User.count} do
  post: users_path, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
end
# Assuming your users table is cleared before each test..
assert_kind_of Tenant, User.first.tenant
```